# Specify multiple test methods to run in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, spock

Is it possible in Intellij to run just some specific test methods within a testsuite (JUnit or Spock)? 
I tryied to solve that with test kind 'patterns', but it seems to me that it only filters on class level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter a specific method in the com.example.project.test.tryTest class, you can use the following syntax:

```
com.example.project.test.tryTest,methodName
```

In this case, you are filtering for the methodName in the tryTest class. It's crucial to note that you need to separate the method name from the class name with a comma (,).

Additionally, in newer versions, you can use the || operator to add multiple tests. For example:

```
com.example.project.test.tryTest,methodName1||com.example.project.test.tryTest,methodName2
```

In previous versions, you can transition to subsequent lines to specify multiple patterns. For instance:

```
com.example.project.test.tryTest,methodName1
com.example.project.test.tryTest,methodName2
```

This way, you can specify multiple tests in a single expression. Therefore, you filter the methods `methodName1` and `methodName2` in the tryTest class in this manner.

I hope these explanations are helpful. Feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: Can you please point to a documentation source? [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#required:~:text=run%20the%20application.-,Test%20kind,-From%20this%20list), this is not mentioned.

Comment: FYI, I just created documentation issue [IDEA-340911](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-340911).

Answer (score 3):

Revising my old answer from early 2020, because IntelliJ IDEA has improved since then. *Abdullah Çiçekli* just wrote a new answer showing how to configure that manually in more recent versions. There is an even easier way in the current IDEA version, though.

Given this test:

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testA() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }

  @Test
  public void testB() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }

  @Test
  public void testC() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Open the "Structure" view and multi-select (press `Ctrl` for single method selection while clicking or `Shift` for range selection). Then right click on one of the selected methods and click the "Run ..." action or, without using the mouse, just press `Ctrl-Shift-F10` while the focus is still on the structure view.

[image: File structure view with selected methods]
IDEA will run the selected tests:

[image: JUnit test result]

---

**Update:** I created documentation issue [IDEA-340913](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-340913) for IntelliJ IDEA, because this is undocumented.

Comment: Please note: As a reaction of you unaccepting my answer after 3.5 years in favour of Abdullah Çiçekli's new answer, I also rewrote my old answer to reflect IDEA 2023.3. I think, my GUI way of solving your problem is easier to implement than manually specifying filter conditions.

Comment: I appreciate your concise guidance on a practical method. Regarding the UI, is it possible to execute tests under distinct test classes concurrently? For example, can we invoke tests like DummyTest.testA() and DummyTest2.testA() simultaneously?

Comment: That is a new question, related by out of scope. I am not near a computer now and cannot test, but feel free to link to your new question.

Comment: One helpful thing I observed: If I select two test methods in the structure window for a test class and then right click ⇾ choose menu `More Run/Debug` ⇾ `Modify Run Configuration`, it shows the similar pattern configuration mentioned in Abdullah Çiçekli's answer. So to quickly run selected test methods from multiple classes, we can do the above process and copy and accumulate the patterns and finally run them in one of the configuration's.

Answer (score 0):

The Intellij *Run/Debug Configurations* pane JUnit type has a "Method" Test kind that allows you to specify *a* single test, but not a list. afaik that's the only built in Intellij mechanism.

Comment: Also: marking tests with @Category("...") is a way to create groupings, though invoking tests with those will go across all of your entire test suite.

Comment: Using @Category("...") is one way to create groups, but I was looking for a way to avoid changing the test code. Unfortunately @kriegaex seems to be right: "There is no multi-select for running tests on method level."

Comment: Agreed. You could also use gradle's test task, triggered from intellij, which gives you more control. And you could also write a clever junit runner that would look at a system property you pass in the intellij run/debug configuration.